# Enable EME in Hls js

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, http-live-streaming, hls.js, eme

Currently I am using hls js with video js and I need to use EME with hls js. Is it possible to use EME with hls js ?

https://www.w3.org/TR/encrypted-media/

https://github.com/dailymotion/hls.js/tree/master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HLS Transport Streams do not conform to CENC, so its not possible to convert broswer side. HLS using fmp4 does. But in this case, you wouldn't need hls.js eaither.

Comment: Thanks szatmary do you know any way to secure m3u8 files from client side

Comment: Note on this question HLS is not the right choice for common encryption but DASH is